# How to create an addition loop of random numbers?

Tags: java, loops

After writing 1 on scanner I want a random dice number generated and after pressing 1 again I want another random number generated but now I want it added with previous number. I want to make a loop,  I want to keep pressing 1 and keep adding random numbers till I reach a certain number.
Thank you.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int s = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println(s);

            int previous = s;
            if (s == 1) {
                Random ran = new Random();
                int n = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;

                System.out.print(n);
                int next;

                while (true) {
                    next = scan.nextInt();

                    if (next == 1) {

                        System.out.println(previous);
                    }

                    previous = n + 10;

                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? Please describe the behaviour of your code, the desired behaviour and how the two differ.

Answer (score 2):

Define `previous` outside the `for loop`, and replace

```
int previous = s; 
previous = n + 10;
```

with

```
previous += s;
previous += n + 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int sum=0;
for(;;)
{
    if(sc.nextInt()==1)
    {
        int num = (int)(Math.random()*6);       // using the pre-defined random function in java.lang.Math class
        System.out.println("Dice Value: "+num);
        sum+=num;                               // shorthand adding the number for each iteration
    }
    //if(sum>100)
    //    break;
    //if statement to check if value of sum is greater/lesser than a specific number 
}
System.out.println("Final Answer: "+sum)
```

Something like this might work (not yet tested): an infinite loop that can be terminated as per choice.

If you are looking for a way that the program works as soon as you physically press the '1' key on your keyboard, without having to press the enter key, something like a keyevent might work:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

Please do let me know if there are any errors or doubts :)